# Creating a fallback if current_user is nil for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, permissions

I have instances in my app that perform actions based on the `current_user` courtesy of Devise. For instance:

**Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def like
    @post.liked_by current_user
  end
end
```

**View**

```
...
<% if current_user.liked? post %>
  <%= link_to "Unlike", unlike_post_path(current_user.to_param, post), method: :put, remote: true %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Like", like_post_path(current_user.to_param, post), method: :put, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

My problem, cross-site is if there is no `current_user` then I'll get a NilClass error. I'm aware of the callback `before_filter :authenticate_user!` but was wondering what would be the best solution where the actions are still visible in the view for both logged in/non-logged in users.

Comment: You can split it into partials. One for logged-in users and one for non logged-in users and make changes accordingly.

Comment: it all depends on what you want to do.  for example, in your `like` method, you can pass an optional parameter in case the `current_user` is not present.  unless you share what you like to do, this question is vague and will be opinion-based so I'm voting to close it off.

Comment: @jvnill I updated my question to include the actions involved within the conditional. Is this the information you were looking for?

Comment: ah it's not that Carl.  If you're looking for a way to fix that particular code in your question, then the answers below will help you.  if you're looking for a more general answer, i'm afraid that your question may not conform to the SO standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise has a helper for this:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.liked?(post) %>
  ...
<% else %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

If they aren't signed in, the second part of the condition will never be evaluated so no Nil error.

Comment: With this I get the error:  `syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' ...in? && current_user.liked? post`

Comment: Add brackets around liked? variable, try that. Otherwise the syntax is fine.

Comment: If still issues, paste your full code in the question.

Comment: No worries. Using brackets around method parameters is preferred practice for exactly this reason - you need to be careful with them when there are multiple conditions or parameters. The Ruby Community Style Guide recommends always using parentheses.

Comment: That's interesting. While reading the book *Eloquent Ruby* they actually have a section, *Parenthesis are Optional but Are Occasionally Forbidden*. I guess things can get misconstrued when they're omitted inside a conditional.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the helper current_user like so:

```
<% if !current_user.nil? && current_user.liked?(post) %>
...
<% else %>
...
<% end %>
```

We are basically telling rails that if the current user is NOT nil and the current user has liked the post then we should see the unlike button, else we see the like button.